# How to update an Eclipse installed via Yoxos

Tags: eclipse, plugins, yoxos

I downloaded and installed Eclipse using Yoxos a few months ago.  Since then, several of the plugins I downloaded as part of the install have been updated.  In particular, the App Engine sdk has gone through 4 or 5 point releases, and GWT went from 1.7 to 2.0.  The yoxos "software updates" tool seems painfully unaware of these updates though.  How do I update these plugins?  Is it a matter of waiting until Yoxos updates their database of plugins?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you not update directly from Eclipse ?

*Help -> Check for updates*

That will normally check for Eclipse framework and plugin updates.

Comment: OK.  problem was that while yoxos includes the plugins for you, they don't include all the update urls.  So eclipse doesn't know to go out to look for them.  I guess the idea is that you would rely on yoxos for all the updates.  Once I added the update site url manually, the "check for updates" picked up the new versions.

Answer (score 0):

You can update from anywhere, Pulse, Eclipse.  If you go to the Eclipse site download page you can see many different providers of updates.  Just get their download links and go to Help -> Install Software and hit the add button to add them.  Then it will pick up updates from any of these sites.  All of the plugins have unique names and versions so it does not matter where you get them.

Answer (score 0):

You can update via the Eclipse mechanisms as the others describe. Then you risk running into the compatibility problems all Eclipse users have that put together plug-ins from a number of update sites. The idea of a distribution like Yoxos is to have a defined state of plug-ins that are checked for compatibility; compare with Linux distributions.
In a distribution you don't always have the latest version of a software, but it works and it's comfortable getting updates.
On Jan 6, the Yoxos Distribution had the latest update that - among others - includes the updates you asked above.
yoxos.ondemand.com also has a feedback button on the right side, so you can get your answers directly from the developers instead of hoping that they find your question in unrelated 3rd party forums :-)

Comment: pretty much every question on stack overflow could be posted on some more specific forum :)  I took the chance on updating the plugins myself, and didn't have any problems.