# Installing new software on Eclipse with Yoxos

Tags: eclipse

I have installed Yoxos on a previously installed version of Eclipse.  I now need to install a plugin in which I need to enter a remote site.  But since the "Yoxos Customizer" link replaces the "Help->Install New Software" link, I cannot install any new plugins that Yoxos does not know about.

Does anyone know how to add new plugins to Eclipse with Yoxos?

Answer (score 1):

I'd say this question has been answered here:

[How to update an Eclipse installed via Yoxos](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1933880/how-to-update-an-eclipse-installed-via-yoxos/2041181#2041181)

In short, the benefits of using Yoxos is to be able to save your customized install of Eclipse + plugins that have undergone quality and compatibility testing.

You may be able to work around this if you really need a specific plugin, but know that you do this *at your own risk*.

See if you can find an archive file of the plugin you want to install, then follow this guide:

http://www.venukb.com/2006/08/20/install-eclipse-plugins-the-easy-way/

Comment: If you're a paying subscriber to Yoxos, perhaps you could also shoot them an email to get the plugin you want included?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you are using Yoxos 5.
In that case, the answer to your question is "Upgrade to the latest version and use a place".
In Yoxos 5 you can set up a place, which is the Yoxos distribution enhanced with 3rd party sites. You find the UI in the Yoxos Launcher at top center.

I encourage you to not follow that description from 2006. Since then many many things changed in both Eclipse and Yoxos and that installation description is just another way of asking for trouble.

Comment: It's asking me to create an account that I have to pay for?

Answer (score 0):

In Yoxos I've installed "Marketplace Client" plugin and then via "Help > Eclipse Marketplace..." I was able to install plugins, which are not available in Yoxos Marketplace.